# How to share a variable and track it's change in multiple components in angular v4 ts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have three components: A, B and C: Component A has a variable x:number and a function to increase the value of the variable. Here is my code snippet.

```
export class AComponent{
   x:number = 1;
   inc():void
   {
      x += 1;
   }
}
```

Both B and C components have the A template which displays the value of the variable x. My question is how do I call the inc() function in component B and change the value in both templates of B and C?

e.g when I click a button in B and increase the value of x by 1 to get 2, both B and C should display 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to create a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    private _x:number = 0;

    get x():number {         
       return this._x;
    }

    inc() {
       this._x = this._x + 1;
    }
}
```

Then, from any of the other components, you just inject the service and use it:

```
export class AComponent {

    constructor(private _svc:MyService) { }

    doSomething() {
        // read the value
        console.log(this._svc.x);

        // increase it
        this._svc.inc();
    }

}
```

Remember to add your service to the `app.module.ts` in the `providers` section.

This specific communication strategy can be found at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

For other methods of communication between componets, check:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#

Comment: You may also interpolate the service variable in the component's template: `<h3>Counter: {{ _svc.x }}</h3>`

Comment: I appreciate that @kontiki, it worked for this `<h3>Counter: {{ _svc.x }}</h3>` when I call the doSomething() function in AComponent. Howerver, I have a BComponent which is supposed to also show the increased counter in it's template without calling doSomething() function in BComponent

Comment: It should work. Here you have a plunker that demonstrates it. You can increment from any component, and it is reflected in all three: https://plnkr.co/4akoOOA1UE1vtZ8eeiAQ